# Switch to LandScape Mode, even if deactivated

Tags: android, settings, landscape, apply

When Landscape Mode is deactivated in the Settings (Or Notification Bar on TouchWiz and HTC devices), how to apply it when the user rotates the device?
I know it's possible to read the accelerometer sensors and write an own routine which sets it, but i bet there is an easier way and no need to reinvent the wheel.

Tips or advices are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Ignoring a user's settings is going to make your app *real* popular, I'm sure.

Comment: The Youtube app does it, i've heard it is popular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is simple way - but it was deactivated by user :)

If you have app that has only landscape orientation you should not worry about current phone orientation. If your app works in both orientations you should not switch orientation, because user specially says "I don't want orientation change!" by switching this setting off.

Comment: You are right about the user not wanting it normally (like in a browser or gallery), but the user rotates the phone in this application, to see additional information. I would like to remove the notification bar. Though if the notification bar is deactivated as well the user has no easy way to activate it (because he needs the additional information). Hence the question.

Comment: As you describe - you have app, that should do some action, dependent on accelerometer. So, just read information from that sensor and do whatever you want. There is no simpler way, if user turn off orientation change